# How can I write to the second line of a file from the command line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have an external program that produces an output file (largish, 20K lines possible).

I need to insert a new line between the existing line 1 and line 2. I've been looking at awk and sed - I use one liners in each fairly regularly - but I haven't been able to come up with the right switches to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{print; print "new line"} NR!=1'
```

Comment: A little shorter: `awk 'NR==2 {print "new line"} 1'`

Comment: @glennjackman: your version doesn't work on my system, but the answer does. Specifically, with yours, line 2 is duplicated and the new line is inserted between both (so as line 3).

Comment: Is there a way to start writing at the 2nd line and overwrite all subsequent lines?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm not quite sure what you're asking for.  Just print the first line of the specified file and a set second line? First line and then the contents of a file? The first line of the first file and then a line from a second file for each remaining line in the first? You may want to ask a new question with a very specific description of what you want, and a relatively short but complete example.

Answer (score 16):

For your specific case, this should be simpler:

```
sed '1 { P ; x }' your-file
```

Explanation: at line **1**, do the following

1. **P**rint the line
2. E**x**change the pattern space with the holding space (basically empties the buffer)

Then, the line (empty now) is printed again as part of the cycle.

---

If you want to add a **new line** instead of a **new line character** (what I understood initially) then just use `sed`'s command `a\` (append):

```
sed '1 a\
appended line' your-file
```

or even

```
sed '1 aappended line' your-file
```

It appends "`appended line`" after line 1.

Comment: `sed -i '1 a\\' file` for just a newline.

Comment: @forcefsck Yes, only disadvantage is that it's a GNUism, as my second `'1 aapended line'` example.

Answer (score 13):

I guess the `sed` approach would be:

`sed '2 i whatever_line_of_text_you_wanted_to_INSERT' filename.txt`

This will get the text into the second line of the file and then the the actual second line with in the file will become the third.

Note that, using *append mode*, if it had to be, it had to use the first line, since the append will happen after the line number noted.

`sed '1 a whatever_line_of_text_you_wanted_to_INSERT' filename.txt`

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers above mention how to save the changes to the original file, which is I think what the OP was asking for.

It's certainly what I needed when I cam to the page.

So assuming your file is called `output.txt`

```
sed -i '1 a This is the second line' output.txt
```

My particular use case is to automatically add an xsl stylesheet declaration to a junit xml file.

```
sed -i '1 a <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="junit-html.xsl"?>' junit.xml
```

Comment: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/04/sed-command-in-linux-append-and-insert-lines-to-file.html is the relevant part of a well written intro to sed.

Comment: this is what I am looking for thanks man...

Answer (score 3):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\n\n\n/' yourBigFile
```

[Explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/167814)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 1G file
```

If you want to insert `something` after the newline:

```
sed '1{G;s/$/something/}' file
```

Or if you sed handles `\n`:

```
sed '1s/$/\nsomething/' file
```

Of course `a` is even easier:

```
sed '1a something' file
```

Comment: I am sorry, what does it do?

Comment: It inserts a newline after line 1

Comment: Or rather appends a newline `\n` to line one!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `ed` for this:

```
(echo 1a; echo 'Line to insert'; echo .; echo w) | ed - filename
```

Similar to a `sed` solution, but without the clutter of escaped newlines.

Comment: You could spare some `echo`'s, especially under `bash`: `ed - filename <<< $'1a\nLine to insert\n.\nw'`.

Comment: Doesn't work in all shells, for example in `dash`, which on many systems is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: That is why I wrote “You could spare _some_ `echo`'s”. Sparing _all_ `echo`'s is indeed `bash` only feature, but reducing the `echo` count from 4 to 1 works in `dash` and `ksh` too: `echo '1a\nLine to insert\n.\nw' | ed - filename`.

Comment: Or just [use `printf %s\\n`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275864/135943), which puts a newline after every arg you give it and doesn't screw up on special characters embedded in the line you want to insert.  Also, why use `ed` when `ex` is available?

Answer (score 1):

**Python Solution**

```
python -c "import sys; lines = sys.stdin.readlines(); lines.insert(1,'New Line\n'); print ''.join(lines).strip()" < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use python for this

```
import fileinput

for linenum,line in enumerate(fileinput,FileInput("file",inplace=1)):
    if linenum ==1:
          print ""
          print line.rstrip() 
      else: 
          print line.rstrip()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and (Bash-specific) ANSI escape codes:

```
# note: \ --> \\
printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 | sed -e $'1 { s/\\(.*\\)/\\1\\\ninserted line/; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just like using an explicit counter:

```
awk '(c==1) {print "new line"} (c!=1) {print $0} {c++}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method uses `printf` and `ex`:

```
printf '%s\n' 1a 'my line to insert' . x | ex file
```

`1a` means "append after first line"; the `.` ends the appending; `x` means save and exit.